# log base 2 in a loop in python 2.7

Tags: python, statistics, nlp

I have the following code:

```
for c in word:
    bigram = prev_char+c
    prev_char = c
    prob_es = prob_es*(float(char_value_es.get(bigram, 0)))
```

probability in this case is a multiplication of each letter in a word.
How can I convert it to the following formula?

prob_es = SUM(log2 p(float(char_value_es.get(bigram, 0)))

```
prob_ca = math.log(prob_ca,2)+math.log((float(char_value_ca.get(bigram, 0)),2))
```

Type of error is:

```
prob_ca = math.log(prob_ca,2)+math.log((float(char_value_ca.get(bigram, 0)),2))
TypeError: a float is required
```

Comment: `math.log(number, 2)` will find the logarithm of `number` with base 2.

Comment: why use a sum? what are `char_value_es`? In short: could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: (char_value_es.get(bigram, 0)) is a stored a value in a text file for each bigram, I'm converting the txt values into numbers and then i compute the probability.

Comment: let's consider (char_value_es.get(bigram, 0)) as a variable X nothing more.

Comment: instead of multiplying values of probabilities, I'm summing the logs of these values instead because of the underflow I'm facing . So I need a way to move from multiplications of values to sum the logs of these values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[9.2.2. Power and logarithmic functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#power-and-logarithmic-functions)

You should initialize your bigram and prob_es values before entering the loop.

Your original code is

```
for c in word:
    bigram = prev_char+c
    prev_char = c
    prob_es *= float(char_value_es.get(bigram, 0))
```

Replace this with

```
import math
bigram = ''
log_es = 0
for c in word:
    bigram = prev_char+c
    prev_char = c
    log_es += math.log(float(char_value_es.get(bigram, 0)))
prob_es = math.exp(log_es)
```

Comment: I have defined the variables in my code but due to the space limit, i did not post my whole code. However, million thanks for the solution. It works!

Comment: @ALS_WV Your welcome, good luck with the rest of the program.